# EF Query to change IQueryable<T> to a superclass of T

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When using inheritence in Entity Framework, OfType<>() to filter a query to only include rows of the specific subclass. The resulting IQueryable is the type of the subclass. Is there a way to do the opposite? to go from a subclass to the superclass?

Here's a basic example doing it the "wrong way", creating a 2nd list on the C# side

```
public class User {}
public class Teacher : User {}
public class Student : User {}
public class Session
{
  Guid Id;
  Teacher Teacher;
  IEnumerable<Student> Students;
}

public IEnumerable<User> GetStudentsAsUsers(Guid sessionId)
{
  List<Student> students = context.Sessions
    .Where(session => session.Id == sessionId)
    .Select(session => session.Students)
    .ToList();

  List<User> users = new List<User>();
  users.AddRange(students);

  return users;
}
```

Comment: Can you not just cast it? Covariance means this should work `return (IEnumerable<User>)students;` or `return (IQueryable<User>)students;` or putting it another way, that cast is implicit so not even needed, just do `return students;`

Comment: in this example it looks like you obviously should be able to just cast the list, but what if i want to do fluent things on the database side that necessitates the use of the superclass for some reason?
I guess that means the provided example is bad.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` is covariant so you can always cast it either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OfType` either way - the only difference is that downcasting is always safe, so it will give you all items (no type checking is needed) as an `IEnumerable<supercclass>`.  It also works for collections of mixed types (meaning it's not *only* used for filtering to subtypes)

I would just do `return students.Cast<User>();` since you know the cast is safe.

Comment: Covariance means you should be able to do just `return students;`

Comment: getting back to this a little late. I don't remember exactly what I did but I encountered an ugly error using OfType<Superclass>() mixed with some other functions. maybe a Select() followed by a Where() assumed it was still of type Superclass